# Easiest way to tokenize/split a string using string delimiters?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, split, token

OK, I admit string manipulation has never been a strong point of mine when it comes to C++, and although i've had quite a success at various cases simply by using Boost, I'm still having some issues.

So, here's what I need (the example is precise)...

---

**The input is :**

`position fen <arg_a1> <arg_a2> ... <arg_aN> moves <arg_b1> <arg_b2> ... <arg_bN>`

(well, for those whose who are familiar with the topic, it's a UCI protocol's command)

**All I want to do is :**

- get `<arg_a1> <arg_a2> ... <arg_aN>` (with the spaces included) into one string (that is the string between `position` and `moves`
- also get `<arg_b1> <arg_b2> ... <arg_bN>` into another string (that is the string from `moves` till the end).

---

I've played a lot with `Boost::split` but obviously this is working much like `strtok` (accepting *character* and *not string* delimiters).

How should I go about that? What's the easiest way to solve this particular issue, without my reinventing the wheel (which I tend to do... quite often... lol)?

***HINT :** Obviously I can do it. But all I could think of right now is quite ugly. What I'm looking for is a C++-friendly way...*

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward. How would you do it if you knew the exact location of the words `position` and `moves`? Now, how would you find the location of those words in the input string? I bet if you put those two things together, a possible solution will be clear.

Comment: You might want to see this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/701092

Comment: +1 for Greg's comment.  Further to that, you should do this using `std::string` functions - there's insignificant benefit from complicating this with boost split, regexps etc.

Comment: @GregHewgill Well, I definitely don't know why I had to read it by someone else, but guess what : It was solved by 2 simple `::find` and `::substr` statements. And for some weird reason, it doesn't strike me as ugly anymore... lol. Thanks, mate! ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Next step: answer your own question below, then accept your answer as being correct.

Comment: @Yakk Correct. Done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**And this the solution** (with some numeric hacks) :

```
    // where are 'fen' and 'moves' within the initial string?
    int fenPos = input.find("fen");
    int movesPos = input.find("moves");

    // get the exact string but taking into account the position of our initial tokens
    // as well as their length (e.g. fenPos.length()+1 = 4, etc)
    string fen = input.substr(fenPos+4,movesPos-fenPos-5);
    string moves = input.substr(movesPos+6);
```

So for input :

`"position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1 moves f2f3 e7e6 g2g4"`, this returns :

```
fen   = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
moves = "f2f3 e7e6 g2g4"
```